# Docker—purge unneeded interfaces

Tags: docker, networking

I am using docker(-compose) mostly for development, so I have a bunch of Projects with one or more containers each on my development machine. I have stopped and removed all containers, but running `docker network ls` still yields:

[image]

and looking at the »connection information« window shows:

[image]

How can I »purge« all unneeded interfaces, which were created by a `docker run …` or `docker-compose up`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all unused networks by running: `docker network prune`

```
> docker network prune --help

Usage:  docker network prune [OPTIONS]
Remove all unused networks
```